# Communicating with a Raspberry Pi Zero W via serial communication

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-communication

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W running a variation of Debian. I am trying to communicate with it from a Linux PC via a micro-USB cable. I have been unable to activate gadget mode and use that, I suspect it is due to the heavily-modified OS.

I have been looking into serial communication with the devices in the /dev directory. To my understanding, they act similarly to how file descriptors work in C?

I have been trying to `echo` text to the device, and am doing that like so:

```
echo test > /dev/ttyS4
```

I have echo'd to my own terminal using this strategy to see if I had any sense of direction, and it did work.

Is it possible to monitor some output on the device and watch for this output?

Or am I completely off track here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pi serial ports are on GPIO pins 14 and 15 (see e.g. https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html); you need a ttl-to-serial adapter (like [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954)) to connect them to your computer. These pins should correspond to device `/dev/serial0` (which is itself a symbolic link to the actual device name, which may be different on different models or different os versions).

If you want to do serial over the microusb port, you **must** enable gadget mode (and specifically enable a serial gadget). There are several articles online that walk you through the process; [this one on adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/serial-gadget) is probably a reasonable place to start.

If you try following those instructions and run into problems, consider opening a new question on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ and include specific details about what you tried, what happened, etc.